# How do I keep registers from being modified without my consent? (inline x86 MASM on VS2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inline-assembly, masm, cpu-registers

I'm trying to make this simple program that emulates a droptower (yes, the amusement park kind) for a school project, I'm using inline MASM32 on VS2015

this is the C code for the function that prints the "elevator" going up:

```
void deSubida() {
   int a = 0;                         
   while (a <= 9) {                 //outer loop
       printf("Subiendo..\n");
        Sleep(900);
         system("cls");
       int x = 9;                      
        while (x >= 0) {           //inner loop
           if (x == a)             //if both the upper
               printf("[x]\n");    //and lower counts match
           else printf("[]\n");    //then print the elevator ([x])
         x--;                      //else print empty box ([ ])    
        }
    a++;                               
   }
```

and this is the "translation" I'm trying to do of that function into asm:

```
int deSubidaASM() {
    char piso[4] = "[x]";
    char pisoVacio[4] = "[ ]";
    char texto[] = "%s\n";

_asm {

        mov ebx, 0             
        mov ecx, 9             


        _while1:               
        cmp ebx, 9             
        jg _fin               



        _while2 :                 
        cmp ecx, 0              
        jle _resetearWhile2             



        cmp ebx, ecx               
        je _printPiso
        jne _printVacio


        _printPiso :
        lea eax, piso            //get the pointer for "[x]"
        push eax                 //pushes it into the stack
        lea eax, texto           
        push eax
        call DWORD ptr printf     //call the printf function
        pop edx                   //clean the stack
        pop edx
        dec ecx
        jmp _while2               

        _printVacio :
        lea eax, pisoVacio
        push eax
        lea eax, texto
        push eax
        call DWORD ptr printf
        pop edx
        pop edx
        dec ecx
        jmp _while2

        _resetearWhile2:
        mov ecx, 9              
        inc ebx
        jmp _while1


        _fin :

}

}
```

The nested loops work properly, the problem is when the printf function is called on the "call DWORD ptr printf" line, the ECX register ends up filled with random hex numbers or some memory address and of course that makes the sequence followed by the inner loop stop at 9 or 8 since the number for the inner loop count is stored in the ECX register turning it into an infinite loop.

What I'm thinking is that at some point either windows or something else uses that register for something during runtime, I've been searching for a command or a way to keep anything other than my program from using those registers while running but I might as well be biased on that one since I'm a beginner at assembly programming, another option I thought of was to use other registers for the counts but I don't know which to use or if the same problem will happen if I use other registers.

Comment: Can you add an additional push and pop to save the register value?

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prevent register re-use by other processes and the OS.

Comment: I should add though, when your process is swapped out of the core in favour of another process, all of your registers are being stored and then restored upon return.

Comment: The calling convention will dictate which registers have to be saved by the caller, and which have to be preserved by the callee. There is no way around it. In most 32-bit calling conventions EAX, EDX, and ECX need to be preserved (if you need to retain their values across a function call) by the _caller_. Prior to a function call push ECX on the stack (or copy it to a register that isn't clobbered across a call - like EBX, ESI, EDI) and then restore it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Petch I used your suggestion to move it to another register (I used ESI) and it worked!.